# Angular error , /$injector/modulerr when uploading site to Azure running fine locally

Tags: angularjs

i have site which is running fine on local IIS server 
but when i uploaded it to Azure , im getting client side angular Error 
which looks like this :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=foo&p1=Error%3A%20…s%2Fjquery%3Fv%3DWmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1%3A1%3A389857)
    at jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1
    at jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1
    at r (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at k (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at vr (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at o (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at ge (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at dc (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
    at a (jquery?v=WmOFE05otlfPFoEooXSOXv5kDdk1U9fDndeuZQZ4Uas1:1)
```

The error stack which i dont know if it is related starting from the HTML page:

The Error from chrome dev tool:

```
   GET http://myapp/aIqzU0=/%7B%7BAppObject_img%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

And then im getting the angular injector error above ? 
what can be the problem ?

Comment: are you using some sort of jquery file loader?

Comment: im using jquery but not as file loader

Comment: this error is suggesting either jquery is trying to load a file for angular, or that angular has jquery as a dependency, but neither of those options make sense.  more code is required to understand what is going on here.

Comment: how can i check which file they are trying to load ? 
the code is huge and not my .. so its problem to send more

Comment: I would probably start with whatever file the module `foo` is in....

Comment: the problem was  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle ...) 
when it combined into 1 script it didnt work when i released it from the bundle and every thing was working ...